# Replacement for a bathroom water drain cylinder

Tags: substitute-tool, bathroom

I have a water drain in the bathroom like the one on this picture

[image: water drain]

Unfortunately, the man who mounted it has lost the plastic cylinder which is inside it. This cylinder has to be there to stop the smell coming from the canal.

Part ot it is submerged into the water, forming a watter barrier for bad smelling air from the canal.

On this simplified picture below the cylinder is in red color:

[image: water drain principle]

Now I am trying to find the same cylinder without success.

I was thinking of making it with 3D printig, but first wanted to ask if someone can find an easier solution, something to use instead the cylinder.

The problem is that in the home improvement or hardware stores there are no "drain inserts" for sale. They have only the whole bathroom drain and no spare parts for it.

This is why I have to buy the whole product and use the part I need and throw away the rest of it. Or I have to find/make something else with similar form to use instead of it.

Comment: This isn't a lifehack, so I'm making it a comment instead of an answer.  I googled "shower drain" and "shower drain insert" and got lots of results for the actual product that are under $10.  If you are near a home improvement or hardware store you should be able to find one.  Good luck.

Comment: The problem is that in the home improvement or hardware stores there are no "drain insert" for sale. They have only the whole bathroom drain and no spare parts for it. This is why I have to buy the whole product and use the part I need and throw away the rest of it. Or I have to find/make something else with similar form to use instead of it.

Comment: Upvoted, this is absolutely a lifehack.

Comment: @Dave:  I wasn't very clear with my comment.  The OP is definitely asking for a lifehack.  My suggested solution, however, is not a lifehack.

Answer (score 1):

Properly, the fellow who lost the plastic piece should replace it at no cost to you or your landlord -- his mistake, his responsibility to correct.

Failing that, however, you may be able to find a standard PVC pipe cap that's the right size to sit on the shoulder inside the drain body, and drill through the interior of the cap to allow water flow and regain the trap function.